# Chart js with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, charts, chart.js

I'm just beginning using chart js and currently I'm trying to display data from an ng-repeat in chart form using chart js.

Previously I was displaying the data in table form like this.

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Name </th>
<th>Season Winners</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="t in trainer" >
<td>{{t.trainer.trainerName}}</td>
<td>{{t.trainer.seasonWinners}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now I'm trying this but I'm unsure how to use the ng-repeat with charts

```
  <div ng-repeat = "data" >
    <canvas id="doughnut" class="chart chart-doughnut"
    chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" height="100px">

    </canvas>
  </div>
```

Finally here is the controller I'm using

```
  angular.module('horseApp.TrainerController',['chart.js']).
  controller('TrainerController', function ($scope, $stateParams, $http) {



    $http.get('restful-services/api/getAllTrainers')
        .success(function (data, status) {
            $scope.trainer = data;

            $scope.labels=[];
            $scope.data=[];

            for(i=0;i<$scope.trainer.length;i++){
                $scope.labels.push($scope.trainer[i].trainerName);
                $scope.data.push($scope.trainer[i].seaonWinners);
            }
              })
        .error(function (error) {
            alert('An error occurred');
        });
           });
```

Appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope it help

JS

```
angular.module('horseApp.TrainerController',['chart.js']).
  controller('TrainerController', function ($scope, $stateParams, $http) {

$scope.config = {
 type: 'doughnut',
 data: {labels: [], datasets: [{data: []}]}
}

$http.get('restful-services/api/getAllTrainers')
    .success(function (data, status) {
        $scope.trainer = data;

        $scope.labels=[];
        $scope.data=[];

        for(i=0;i<$scope.trainer.length;i++){
            $scope.config.data.labels.push($scope.trainer[i].trainerName);
            $scope.config.data.datasets[0].data.push($scope.trainer[i].seaonWinners);
        }
          })
    .error(function (error) {
        alert('An error occurred');
    });
       });

 angular.module('horseApp.TrainerController').
  directive('chartJs', function (){

     return {
         restrict: 'E',
         scope: {
           config: '='
         },
         template: '<canvas width="400" height="400"></canvas>'
         link: function(scope, elem, attr) {

             var ctx = elem.getContext("2d");

             var chart = new Chart(ctx, scope.config);

         }
     }

  })
```

HTML

```
<div>
   <chart-js data-config="config"></chart-js>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. When I tried that it gave me this error

Comment: Expected expression in form of '_item_ in _collection_[ track by _id_]' but got 'config'.

Comment: Oh, my fault. I updated my answer, look, You actually should not use `ng-repeat`, so I made a directive for `<chart-js>`,so you pass `scope.config` in and create chart js instance

Comment: I put the chart-js directive in an ng-repeat but I cannot get it to work. For some reason it renders as 0px width 0px height. Any clues what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have even copied the data from chart.js documentation and passing it in the directive to test if my data format is correct. Still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to `chart-type`, the classname cannot be `chart-pie` or `chart-bar`, it should be `chart-base`, and you additionally specify `chart-type` in element properties like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="(name,options) in charts">
   <canvas id="{{options.name}}" class="chart chart-base" chart-type="options.type" chart-data="options.data" chart-labels="options.labels">
   </canvas>
</div>
```